# Sencha Touch: One view with different content each time

Tags: json, view, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am very beginner on Sencha touch and need some help.
I have implemented a list and a view which contains one image, some text and a video. I want to use the same view but with different content with respect to which item in list is clicked. For example if the first item is clicked then show the view with image1, text1, and video1, if the second is clicked then the view with image2, text2 video2 and so on...
My thought is to create a json which contains all the content (image1, text1, video1 and image2, ...). My issue is how can I implement this? How can I retrieve the data and show different content in the same view? Is there any tutorial?

Comment: i can answer your question, but post your model, views code.. so that my answer will be more specific

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Xtemplate](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate), it takes a template which defines how data is structured in HTML form and the data(json obj) which is rendered using templates. In you case you should create details view on list `itemtap` event and show it after using [setData](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-setData). If another item in list is tapped hide/destroy the details view and show/create details view and setData which is related to that particular list item(record). Alternatively you can use [Navigation view](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/guide/navigation_view)